# User is redirecting to login page after logout, Keycloak, SSO

Tags: redirect, single-sign-on, keycloak, identity-management, redhat-sso

am using keycloak SSO for login to my application. The issue is very strange, previously everything was working fine and then suddenly the issue occurred.

When user hits the logout button user is getting redirected to login page.

One thing I have observed. When I try to logout from my machine everything is working fine. When I try to logout on users machine am facing the issue.

> My Observation

1. When I logout on my machine the URL in the browser is : **[www.xyz.com/logout](http://www.xyz.com/logout)**
2. When I logout on user machine the URL in browser is   : **[www.xyz.com/logout?state=L2VzYw%3D%3D](http://www.xyz.com/logout?state=L2VzYw%3D%3D)**